# Cannot remotely connect to Windows 10 server on VS Code

Tags: windows-10, ssh, remote, visual-studio-code, macos-ventura

I have recently received a new MacBook (M1) with macOS Ventura 13.1. I want to remotely connect to a Windows 10 server but fail every time to do so with this new MacBook. My initial thought was this might be caused by incompatible versions of ssh as my MacBook has `OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6` and the windows server has `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2`. However I AM able to connect to a Linux server that has an even older version of ssh - `OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips`.

I am also able to ssh to the windows server on Terminal, no problem.

When connecting to the Windows server on VSCode, after entering its password I get

> Could not establish connection to "aaa-bbb": Connecting with SSH
> timed out.

Part of the output shown on VSCode is shown below

```
[x] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: "-v -T -D ... -o ConnectTimeout=15 aaa-bbb"
[x] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=...
[x] stderr> OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[x] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-... ...
[x] Got askpass request: {"request":"uid@aaa-bbb password:"}
[x] Showing password prompt
[x] Listening for interwindow password on ... ...
[x] Writing password prompt to globalState
[x] Got password response
[x] Interactor gave response: ***************
[x] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[x] stderr> Authenticated to aaa-bbb (... ...) using "password".
[x] > ready: ...
[x] > MINGW64_NT-10.0-19044 3.1.7-340.x86_64 2021-03-26 22:17 UTC
[x] Terminating local server
[x] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at g.Timeout (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0/out/extension.js:...)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/myuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0/out/extension.js:...)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:...)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:...)
[x] Local server exit: 15
[x] ------
```

**UPDATE**:
After trying `ssh -v -T -D 51756 -o ConnectTimeout=15 aaa-bbb` (which is shown on the output above) on Terminal, I get `debug1: update_known_hosts: known hosts file /Users/llc10/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist`.

`ssh -v -D 51756 -o ConnectTimeout=15 aaa-bbb` worked and it is connected to the server. Is this what caused the problem above? If so, how do I avoid using `-T` when connecting to the server on VS Code??

**UPDATE #2**:
Currently it doesn't seem to be possible to exclude the -T command in VS Code .. [Ref link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7558)

Is there a way to achieve this?